# Bad Encoding of the × character in Encoding(932) (SJIS)... resulting in the ? character

Tags: c#, encoding

I try to encode the × character in a SJIS encoded file... but it doesnt succeed.
I do something like:

```
string strJapaneseCross = new string('\uC397',1);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(strJapaneseCross);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(filesPath, "MyInfo.txt"), false, Encoding.GetEncoding(932)))
 {
     sw.Write(sb.ToString());
 }
```

The resulting file is not encoded well, instead of 0x817E in the file (corresponding to **×** in SJIS) I have 0x3F, which stands for **?**

There doesnt seem to be any problem with other japanese character I encode. What I am doing wrong ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `\uC397` is 쎗, a Korean character. `×` is `\u00D7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\u escape codes work with the Unicode code points, not the UTF-8 encoding of them. Hence, you're actually asking to get U+C397 converted, and that is a completely different character - specifically 쎗, a Korean character.

The actual Unicode code point of × is U+00D7, so you want to write:

```
string strJapaneseCross = new string('\u00D7',1);
```